# incrementing box-shadow css in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

box-shadow has a syntax like this

```
box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset;
```

I would like to set up a jQuery function that increments the h-shadow, v-shadow, and blur by 2px everytime a button click takes place. What would it look like?

```
$('button[type=submit]').bind('click': function(){
                                   $('div').css('box-shadow'???, '+=2');
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #test{ box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
    button{ height: 20px; width: 100px}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#test").css('box-shadow', incValues($("#test").css('box-shadow')));
        });
    });

    function incValues(values){
        var splits = values.split('px');
        splits[0] = splits[0].split(' ');
        splits[0] = splits[0][splits[0].length-1];
        return (parseInt(splits[0])+2) +'px ' + (parseInt(splits[1])+2) +'px ' + (parseInt(splits[2])+2) +'px ';
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='test'></div>
    <br/>
    <button>Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do that by using a couple of regular expressions to get the color, hshadow, vshadow, blur, spread and whether it is inset or not. Once you ve got that, you can simply increment it by 2. Put it all together and apply to the button.

Here's the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zxya8/1/) (with the color and inset values obtained from the original box-shadow CSS. This is how it would look (updated):

```
var pattern = /\d+px/g;    //will match only those values with a number + px
var colorPattern = /rgb\(.+\)/;  //regex to get the color
var incr = 2;
$('#btn').bind('click', function(){
    var currentBoxShadowCSS = $(this).css('box-shadow');
    var color = currentBoxShadowCSS.match(colorPattern)[0];
    /*
    That will get us the color:
    rgb(255, 0, 0)
    */
    var matchesArr = $(this).css('box-shadow').match(pattern);   
    /* 
    That will return ["0px", "0px", "5px", "0px"] 
    That s basically [h-shadow, v-shadow, blur, spread]
    We are concerned with only the first 3
    */
    var oldHShadow = matchesArr[0].split('px')[0];
    var newHShadow = parseInt(oldHShadow, 10) + incr;

    var oldVShadow = matchesArr[1].split('px')[0];
    var newVShadow = parseInt(oldVShadow, 10) + incr;

    var oldBlur = matchesArr[2].split('px')[0];
    var newBlur = parseInt(oldBlur, 10) + incr;

    //check if this was an inset shadow
    var inset = currentBoxShadowCSS.indexOf('inset') > -1 ? ' inset': '';
    //we got what we need, apply it
    $(this).css('box-shadow', newHShadow + 'px ' + newVShadow + 'px ' + newBlur + 'px ' + color + inset);
});
```

Comment: If the shadow is inset then it removes the inset property.

Comment: I suppose that s a pretty straightforward thing to add in though I doubt if the questioner really wants to decrease the box shadow of a button with a inset box-shadow. Over time the button will look weird.

Comment: Thanks for point that out, I ve updated that in the code (and in the jsfiddle)