# Getting value of individual box-shadow when set to multiple values

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to get an answer to a recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18692541/1926369), I tried to parse the box-shadow of an element, that had been set as

```
div {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px green, 0 0 0 10px #ff0000,  0 0 0 15px blue;    
}
```

I expected to get that string, do an split(",") on it, and get the array of box-shadows. (with 3 elements)

My problem is that I get the string as

```
"rgb (0, 255, 0) 0 0 0 5px, rgb (255, 0, 0) 0 0 0 10px, rgb (0, 0, 255) 0 0 0 15px"
```

And of course when I split that I get a mess.

Is there an **easier** way to get the values of the individual box-shadows ?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396649/incrementing-box-shadow-css-in-jquery

Comment: @Mirage Thanks !! Interesting answer; specially the second one. However, extending that to a list of box-shadows seems too complicated and error-prone ..

Comment: what are you splitting on? would splitting on `rgb` work?

Comment: I am splitting on comma, because it's the only data that I trust. I don't trust rgb values coming first, specially since the formal specification is that the color is last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try three separate statments

```
document.getElementById('the-element-id').style['boxShadow']
```

or do the split but use "px, " as the separator and add the "px" back to all values of the array except the last one

```
var string ="rgb (0, 255, 0) 0 0 0 5px, rgb (255, 0, 0) 0 0 0 10px, rgb (0, 0, 255) 0 0 0 15px";

var array= string.split("px, ");
var length = array.length;
for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
    if (i != length - 1){
        array[i] = array[i] + "px";
    }
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5npH/1)

[EDIT]

I just realized this won't work if the last value of the box shadow is 0 (ie 15px 0 0 0, rgb)

here's the alternative in that case split on ", rgb" and add "rgb" back to all the values of the array except the first one:

```
var string ="rgb (0, 255, 0) 0 0 0 5px, rgb (255, 0, 0) 0 0 0 10px, rgb (0, 0, 255) 0 0 0 15px";

var array= string.split(", rgb");
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0 ){
        array[i] = "rgb" + array[i];
    }
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLYh3/1/)

Comment: Nice try, +1 for that. But I am unsure that I can trust the rgb value coming first across all browsers.

Comment: what about the first suggestion...assigning ids to the three elements you need to get the box shadow from and then just calling document.getElementById('the-element-id').style['boxShadow'] for each?

Comment: But there is only 1 element, that has 3 box-shadows set; I don't have 3 elements ...

Comment: This will not work if shadow has rgb with alfa i.e. rgba